# I cannot get data from the same database on different hosts with different versions of mysql-server

Tags: apache-2.4, mysql5, phpmyadmin, mysql5.6, php56

I have a web site that has moved to a new server.
I moved the site to a web-server running apache24 and php56. It came from a server with apache24 and php55.

When I use the old external (different host/server) database that runs mysql57 all goes well. But when I try to connect to the database on the mysql56 server I cannot access the data. The connecting goes fine, but no data is returned.

I used phpMyadmin to export the data from the old server and import it to the new. On both servers I use the same credentials. I checked both in PHPMyadmin as in the cli mysql client, the credentials are correct. I can see the database, the tables, and also the data in the tables.

I suspect that the different versions of mysql has to do with this but have no clue how to tackle this problem. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would someone move the db instance to a lower version in the first place? Upgrade your new host db instance to the version you had it working.

Comment: Because It is not under my control.

Comment: Do you have error logging turned on for your mysql instance? If not turn it on. Then try and do one of the requests that doesn't work and look at the output of the log - it will hopefully give some clue as to what's happening.

Comment: The software of the website is actually quite old and did not update for years. In the past it also ran well with mysql55 and mysql56. If I really need to I will try to get another version of the database, but I also would like to understand what the problem might be.